# Eclipse IDE, Ubuntu, Java how to compile a program to a standalone runable?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am trying to compile two java programs in Eclipse on Ubuntu. I then want to be able to go from two terminal and run the programs; server and client. I am fairly new to eclipse and ubuntu, how would I go about doing this. Such as using g++ and it spitting out a.out or whatever you might call it, how can I do this with eclipse and a Java program?

Don't I need to run them in the JVM? I know java is compiled to java bytecode and ran on a JVM. But this is the first time I have tried to just run a java program a have written in eclipse, outside of eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run the program outside of eclipse there are several ways, i enslist some opportunities below :

- Get the dist folder copy it somewhere and executing the program from here passing the main class name as jvm argument
- Export the program as a runnable jar

To export as a runnable jar the procedure is as follow :

1. Highlight the appropriate file/project
2. `File -> Export`
3. Choose "Runnable JAR file" -> Next
4. Make sure the right project is selected under the "Launch Configuration" dropdown and select "Package required libraries into generated JAR file" under the "Library Handling" section and make sure it's going to the correct export destination.
5. click Finish
6. Run the jar with the command : `java -jar yourjarname.jar`

Since seems that you are familiar with gcc there could be even another option : compile the java program into a standard executable with [gcj](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) gcc extension, there is also the eclipse plugin [GCJBuilder](http://gcjbuilder.sourceforge.net/) ...

Comment: Thank you this works for me. Would that command 'java -jar yourname.jar' also work on windows with the same .jar files?

Comment: :-) the smile kinda of made that comment creepy. But because I can do it on windows too, thank you.